# Python - UnicodeDecodeError while listing directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I am trying to build a list of all files in a directory in Python 2.7 but end up with a UnicodeDecodeError no matter what I seam to do.

My code is:
dirList = os.listdir(directory)

```
for entry in dirList:
    #all 3 tested seperatly
    fullPath = directory+'/'+entry#throws exception
    entry = entry.encode('ascii', 'ignore')#throws exception
    entry = unicode(entry.strip(codecs.BOM_UTF8), 'utf-8')#throws exception
```

I end up with this error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

The exception is always raised when `entry` has a non-ascii character in it. The affending word it usually dies on is "Elavhõbe". When I print it out with `print entry`, it shows Elavhobe (notice the changed 'o').

Strangely, whenever I try through an SSH connection, I can just put them together with `directory+'/'+entry` and I *never* get an exception.

My end goal is to build a full directory path and pass it to `os.path.isdir(fullPath)`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution finally. Since I am not very good with python I am not sure exactly how it works, just that it does.

I added this to the top of my file:

```
import sys

#reload sys and set the default encoding to utf-8
#this will avoid errors when running as host server on server startup
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Then I encode my entry as ascii like this:

```
entry = entry.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

and then everything works just fine. Hope this helps someone someday.